# How to restrict jQuery UI Datepicker to disallow dates in the future?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using a jQuery UI Datepicker, such that only Sunday can be selected.

What I would like to happen is have it where no dates from the current date into the future can be selected. Here is the code I am using currently:

```
var daysToDisable = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

        $('#startdate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
        });

        function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **maxDate** property to prevent the selection of future dates.

Note: this assumes your **dateFormat** is *dd/mm/yy*

**Edit:** http://jsfiddle.net/jXGZz/

```
var fullDate = new Date();

var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);

$('#startdate').datepicker({
    maxDate: fullDate.getDate() + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear(),
    beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
});


function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    if(date.getDay()==0){
        return [true];
    }else{
        return [false];
    }
}
```

Modified twoDigitMonth

```
var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth()+1<10 ? "0"+fullDate.getMonth()+1 : fullDate.getMonth()+1 ;
```

Comment: Yes but would this continue to change each day? I do need someone to select a day as the day becomes available, just not have the option to pick the next Sunday since it is not here yet?

Comment: Yes. I don't quite understand what you mean, but this uses the current date (as in, whatever date it happens to be every time the script is opened).

Comment: Calum, thank you for taking the time to help with this. I had someone put together the code that I am using and I don't quite undertand how to implement what you have added with your code. I use mm/dd/yyyy when this is reported.

Comment: This code should do it all for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jXGZz/ Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Calum, this is exactly what I need but it is starting in March and not allowing me to go forward to August?

Comment: That's because you're aren't using the correct dateFormat (the perfect one being dd/mm/yy of course). Glad you got it working :) please mark this as the answer if you feel so inclined.

Comment: your twoDigitMonth is giving me 012 for December

Comment: I'm using a modified version of this now var currentMonth = fullDate.getMonth()+1<10 ? "0"+fullDate.getMonth()+1 : fullDate.getMonth()+1 ;

Answer (score 32):

I would just use the single entry to restrict the date to nothing beyond today:

```
$('#startdate').datepicker({
    maxDate: '+0d'
});
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer due to its simplicity.

Comment: Brilliant. Way more simple and still extremely effective.

Comment: Indeed. Could not be more simple and understandable.

Answer (score -1):

please do call the datepicker like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#startdate').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this? I have this wrapped in the jQuery ready function. I just sent the code for the datepicker without the need to show that it is already wrapped in the ready function.